# Where can I buy School Days HQ in Greece?

Tags: merchandise, school-days, greece

Do you mind telling me if there is a shop in Greece that sells School Days HQ?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.jastusa.com/catalog/product/view/id/327

Your best bet would be buying it digitally from the official website above. I highly doubt there are shops that stock a decent selection of eroge visual novels in Greece.